# IF OR conditions & FILTER in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

If column A = "blue", OR column A = "red" AND column B = "sold", get sum of column C

Here are my attempts:

```
=SUMIFS(or(C:C, A:A, "blue", A:A, "red"),B:B="sold")
```

Here is a filter that returns N/A because I need to put an OR statement between "blue" and "red" query.

```
=sum(filter(C:C,A:A="blue",A:A="red",B:B="sold")

=sum(filter(OR(C:C,A:A="blue",A:A="red"),B:B="sold")
```

Does not work.

**SOLVED!**

```
=sum(filter(C:C,(A:A="blue")+(A:A="red"),(B:B="sold"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C:C*((A:A="blue")+(A:A="red")*(B:B="sold")))
```

Equivalent to

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(C:C*((A:A="blue")+(A:A="red")*(B:B="sold")))
```

Comment: Thanks you got me on the right track with the +